# Consecutive infinitives

Tags: infinitives

Is there a rule governing when it is acceptable to position two infinitives in a row?

E.g.: The witness plans to refuse to testify.

Comment: Seems like once you got into a third level you couldn't use just infinitives: "The witness refuses to consider to agree to testify" < bad. "The witness refuses to consider agreeing to testify."  I don't really know the applicable rules tho so I'll leave it to another to answer!

Comment: I wonder if there's really any special restriction on infinitives? As with, say, nested genitives ("the girl next door's uncle's godfather's mother-in-law"), provided that the sentence is actually grammatical, then it's more a question of when you reach practical limits of how many 'nested items/ideas' can be processed in a given context. But it's not clear to me that infinitives constitute a special case as such.

Comment: @sequoiamcdowell, The problem with that sentence is that *consider to agree* is ungrammatical all by itself—*consider* doesn’t take an infinitive. So it really doesn’t have anything to do with chains of infinitives.

Comment: Incidentally—I think I remember reading that there is no easy rule that tells which verbs take an infinitive (*plan to clean up*), which ones take a present participle (*consider cleaning up*), which ones take the plain verb (*help clean up*), and which don’t take a second verb at all (* *scheme to clean up*). That means that if you’re a native speaker, you’ve just memorized them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no grammatical limit. The sentence could continue *The witness refuses to consider to agree to testify to help to free . . .*  However, anyone writing like that would quickly try the patience of the reader.

Comment: +1 for trying patience. For informal (non-legal) writing I might set an -- arbitrary -- limit around five or six consecutive infinitive clauses, if only for readability's sake. *Just keep in mind you're pushing it if you're using more than three for most situations.*

Comment: Barrie, your example sounds off to me, because of *consider*. I don’t think *consider* can take an infinitive complement (except in the idiom *consider X to be Y*, but of course that’s another story).

Comment: But will he be likely to continue to refuse to try to consider to begin to negotiate to testify to start to help to arrange to free the accused?

Comment: You're right, Jason, it was a poor example. The point remains, however, that there is not a grammatical limit, even if there is a lexical one.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Perhaps change the answer to make it more correct?

Answer (score 1):

No. This is a style choice. Once you get past two infinitives, however, you might start considering revisions, simply for the sake of flow and ease of reading.

E.g.: **3** infinitives: The witness refuses *to consider to agree to testify.* **2:** The witness refuses *to consider* agreeing *to testify*. **1:** The witness won't consider agreeing *to testify*.